# How to iterate over given JSON file data by tag Value

Tags: python, json

I want to know how to iterate over json file by passing value for tag key in inner dictionary.
For example if i pass 90s it shoul return name of the movie and tag values that contain 90s in its list.
please find json example below

```
{ "items": [
 {"name": "The Shawshank Redemption", "tags": ["90s", "drama"]},
 {"name": "The Godfather", "tags": ["70s", "drama", "crime"]},
 {"name": "The Dark Knight", "tags": ["action", "crime", "drama"]},
 {"name": "The Godfather: Part II", "tags": ["70s", "crime", "drama"]},
 ...]
```

}

I expect if i search for 90s or drama or crime or movie name it should return respective dictionary that contains any of these values in tag list or name of movie

Comment: We're not here to write code for you. Post the code that you already tried and doesn't work and we'll try to tell you the hows and whys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension to find all movies with a certain tag.

```
data = { "items": [
 {"name": "The Shawshank Redemption", "tags": ["90s", "drama"]},
 {"name": "The Godfather", "tags": ["70s", "drama", "crime"]},
 {"name": "The Dark Knight", "tags": ["action", "crime", "drama"]},
 {"name": "The Godfather: Part II", "tags": ["70s", "crime", "drama"]},
]}

def find_movies_by_tag(tag):

    #Get all dictionaries, for which the tag matches a tag in value list for tags
    return [item for item in data['items'] if tag in item.get('tags')]

print(find_movies_by_tag('drama'))
print(find_movies_by_tag('crime'))
print(find_movies_by_tag('70s'))
```

The output will then be:

```
print(find_movies_by_tag('drama'))
#[{'name': 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'tags': ['90s', 'drama']}, {'name': 'The Godfather', 'tags': ['70s', 'drama', 'crime']}, {'name': 'The Dark Knight', 'tags': ['action', 'crime', 'drama']}, {'name': 'The Godfather: Part II', 'tags': ['70s', 'crime', 'drama']}]

print(find_movies_by_tag('crime'))
#[{'name': 'The Godfather', 'tags': ['70s', 'drama', 'crime']}, {'name': 'The Dark Knight', 'tags': ['action', 'crime', 'drama']}, {'name': 'The Godfather: Part II', 'tags': ['70s', 'crime', 'drama']}]

print(find_movies_by_tag('70s'))
#[{'name': 'The Godfather', 'tags': ['70s', 'drama', 'crime']}, {'name': 'The Godfather: Part II', 'tags': ['70s', 'crime', 'drama']}]
```

Comment: Hi Devesh thanks for your response, i tried your solution but its showing error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Fixed @vineetsingh Please run again and it should work perfectly now :)

Comment: Hi @Devesh I'm getting this error : AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'get' after running

Comment: Which line? In the function `find_movies_by_tag` ?

Comment: this one : return [item for item in jsondata['items'] if tag in item.get('tags')]

Comment: You have the `...` in your items dictionary in the question which is throwing this error, use the dictionary the way I have defined in my code, and it should work fine for you @vineetsingh

Comment: Thanks devesh it's working fine now thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @vineetsingh, you accepted and then unaccepted my answer, was something not working in my code?

Comment: actually i tried to accept steve solution too but i guess stackoverflow allows only one solution to get accepted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately you can only accept one solution, but as you get more reputation, you can upvote the other answers you like!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that returns a list of all of the movies that contain the specified tag:

```
import json

jsondata = """ { "items": [ {"name": "The Shawshank Redemption", "tags": ["90s", "drama"]},
 {"name": "The Godfather", "tags": ["70s", "drama", "crime"]},
 {"name": "The Dark Knight", "tags": ["action", "crime", "drama"]},
 {"name": "The Godfather: Part II", "tags": ["70s", "crime", "drama"]}
]}"""

data = json.loads(jsondata)


def findMoviesByTag(tag):
    r = []
    for item in data['items']:
        if tag in item['tags']:
            r.append(item)
    return r

result = findMoviesByTag("90s")
if len(result) == 0:
    print("no matches")
else:
    print(result)
```

Result:

```
[{'name': 'The Shawshank Redemption', 'tags': ['90s', 'drama']}]
```

Or for:

```
print(findMoviesByTag("70s"))
```

Result:

```
[{'name': 'The Godfather', 'tags': ['70s', 'drama', 'crime']}, {'name': 'The Godfather: Part II', 'tags': ['70s', 'crime', 'drama']}]
```

Comment: Hi @Steve thanks for your response, i tried your solution and its working fine with break statement below r.append(item) but when i'm removing break statement i'm getting error : TypeError: 'ellipsis' object is not subscriptable. any idea why i'm getting this error.

Comment: No, I can't think of what that would be.  I probably need to see your code to know.  Did you see my newer code?  You get back a list, and then you could just pick off the first item if you wanted just one match.  You could check for no matches by testing for `len(result) == 0`.

Comment: Note that your data can either be JSON or Python code.  In this particular case, they'd be the same.  If you really want to read from a file, you'd want the data to be in JSON format, which is what I show here per the title of your question.

Comment: Hi @Steve Thanks for your response and help it's working fine, actually i didn't did this data = json.loads(jsondata), i was directly doing operation on jsondata, maybe that's why it's showing me that error, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh...now I see where that error was coming from.  You left the '...' in your data.  That was screwing up your data.  Glad I could help.